# What is the relationship based on shared DNA

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

We are trying to find out information regarding my mothers biological father side of the family. My mom was adopted in 1945 and later in life discovered her biological mother but not her biological father. We don’t have much details about him only that he was an American solider based in the UK around 1944. My mom received her DNA results and there was a match showing 752cM shared DNA. My heritage is suggesting that the relationship is great Niece, 1st cousin- 1st cousin once removed. The person is allot younger than my mother (42) and my mom is 76 so I’m guessing the relationship can only be great Niece.

Is it possible with the shared DNA that the relationship is half niece?

We’ve been in contact with this person and they have mentioned that her grandfather was in the US Military and was in the was possibly based in the UK. So I believe this fits! That would also suggest that this person mother is my mothers half sibling. She has also agreed to take a DNA test.

Am I on the right track based on the shared DNA with this lady and my Mom?

Comment: https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/752